# Master-Detail Sample Code for MVC 3 Razor (using Ajax for details)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am looking for sample code to create a master/details with c# mvc 3.

Specifically, I am trying to figure out how to call via ajax the rendering of a partial view.  I am able to put the partial view on the form but want to populate it after a user has selected an item from a select list via ajax.

thx

Comment: can you post the code you have so far?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As always you start with the model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class DetailsViewModel
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // TODO: don't hardcode, fetch from repository
        var model = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => new MyViewModel
        {
            Id = x,
            Title = "item " + x
        });
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        // TODO: don't hardcode, fetch from repository
        var model = new DetailsViewModel
        {
            Foo = "foo detail " + id,
            Bar = "bar detail " + id
        };
        return PartialView(model);
    }
}
```

and corresponding views.

`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>

<ul>
    @Html.DisplayForModel()
</ul>

<div id="details"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.detailsLink').click(function () {
            $('#details').load(this.href);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

`~/Views/Home/Details.cshtml`:

```
@model DetailsViewModel
@Model.Foo
@Model.Bar
```

`~/Views/Home/DisplayTemplates/MyViewModel.cshtml`:

```
@model MyViewModel
<li>
    @Html.ActionLink(Model.Title, "details", new { id = Model.Id }, new { @class = "detailsLink" })
</li>
```

Comment: This worked great.  I do however have follow up problem/question.  So I am loading a partial view in the #details section based on a selection on a treeview.  This works.
 
Currently, what is happening after the user hits 'save' in the #details section is that the entire page is loaded and it says 'save'.  help?
In the #details section I am putting a partial view with a form.  When the  user hits 'Save' I want to put 'Successful Save' in the #details section once again.  But notice however that this form is from an ajax response and now I want in the #details another response from ajax.

Answer (score 1):

I have [blogged](http://zahidadeel.blogspot.com/2011/05/master-detail-form-in-aspnet-mvc-3-i.html) about creating master detail form using asp.net mvc where you can add n child records on clietn side without the need of sending ajax request just to bring the editor fields for child records. it used jquery templates