# MVC Master Detail implementation and alternatives

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, implementation, master-detail

I have been trying to implement a Master Detail solution to my MVC website however I have been having a couple of issues.

I have researched plenty of articles which all seem to work well enough, however I haven't found an example without at least a couple issues:

- Some use tables which I am really trying to avoid
- Some use specialised packages, again I want to avoid using too many non-standard scripts
- Most use a lot of jQuery script

So my questions are;

1. Is there a best practice way to implement a Master Detail solution with CRUD functionality?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532568/master-detail-sample-code-for-mvc-3-razor-using-ajax-for-details

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Detail-CRUD-Operations-fbe935ef

Comment: That first one looks useful, thanks. I have already looked into the second one, but that one uses tables and a ton of scripting!

Comment: Figures. Microsoft over-engineering.  Tables are OK for the part that looks like a table.